# Node.js / Amazon Product API

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm playing around with [node-apac](https://github.com/dmcquay/node-apac) but I'm unsure how to call the opHelper.execute function:

```
var util = require('util'),
  OperationHelper = require('apac').OperationHelper;

var opHelper = new OperationHelper({
  awsId:     '[YOUR AWS ID HERE]',
  awsSecret: '[YOUR AWS SECRET HERE]',
  assocId:   '[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]'
  // xml2jsOptions: an extra, optional, parameter for if you want to pass additional options for the xml2js module. (see https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js#options)
});

opHelper.execute('ItemSearch', {
  'SearchIndex': 'Books',
  'Keywords': 'harry potter',
  'ResponseGroup': 'ItemAttributes,Offers'
}, function(err, results) { // you can add a third parameter for the raw xml response, "results" here are currently parsed using xml2js
  console.log(results);
});
```

If I just wanted a button to display the results when clicked how do I do it?

```
<button onclick = "execute()">
```

I'm totally lost!

Comment: node-apac is a node module, for server side code. You need to host an http server somehow, and return it to the client. Start with an express js tutorial

Comment: Ahhhh I get you.  Ok perfect thanks!